# Different applications rendering fonts in different scale

Tags: windows-7, fonts

Why is it that different applications display fonts in different scale? For example "Consolas 10" is rendered larger in one application than the same font +size in another application. Is it result of some mistake app developers do? Or is the issue deeper, maybe caused by the OS platform?

**Example**

This is what I end up with when setting font to Consolas 10 in 4 different applications [IntelliJ Idea, Sublime Text, Notepad++, command prompt]
[image]

And this is what I have to set to get identical(?) character sizes:[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Point vs Pixel: What is the difference?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/199). As noted in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/12644), in CSS (and possibly in Windows) *1 px = 0.75 pt*, so **10 pt = 13.3 px**.